# What is the TeX code for this character?

Tags: equations

[image]

I'm aware of the command for just the regular sigma:

```
\sum_{{a,b \geq1}}
```

How do I add the second line with

`a \geqb`?

Comment: Off-topic: `\sum` produces a larger symbol than `\Sigma`, let alone `\sigma`, does.

Comment: I was not aware of that, thank you. Also, by off-topic, do you mean that my post will be flagged? I wasn't aware that we are not allowed to post such queries here. I'll delete the post if required.

Comment: @NikilKumar No, your post is not flagged, because it is not off topic. Mico's comment does not help answer the question, so he wrote "Off topic".

Comment: oh okay. I misunderstood @Mico's comment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @James I'll close the post then

Comment: Hi Nikil Kumar.  Welcome to the site!  If others agree with me, your question might be closed eventually by the moderators.  No offense is intended by my suggested duplicate.  We want to keep duplicate questions off the site to avoid having multiple good answers spread out amongst many pages.  Please continue asking questions, but always do your best to search the existing questions first.

Comment: @James I'm not offended at all, I'm sorta regular to the math stack exchange. I understand, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `\substack`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{\substack{a,b \geq 1 \\ a\geq b}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]